# Cannot apply Encrypted attribute to shared Vista folder

Tags: windows-vista, efs

I have a folder on Windows Vista Business that is shared.  When I try to encrypt the folder (apply the Encrypted attribute), I get an error message:

> An error occurred applying attributes to the file
>
> C:\My\Shared\Folder
>
> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process.

How do I encrypt the shared file.  Note: There will be only one other computer accessing the file, and it will connect with local user credentials from the computer that is doing the sharing.

Comment: I would unshare the folder, encrypt it, then reshare it.  However, seems odd to share an encrypted folder.

Comment: @zackrspv: Two people in accounting need to share some files.  Encrypted so that, if a computer is stolen, a third-party cannot read the files without an account password.

Comment: Well, give it a shot; stop sharing it first, then reboot, then encrypt it, then share it again.  Reboot isn't necessary, but I often like the system to clear itself out.